# Jest toMatchSnapshot() works on Node 14 but gives RangeError: Invalid string length on later versions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

This is my test:

```
test('render without crashing', () => {
    const {baseElement} = render(<App />);

    expect(baseElement).toBeDefined();
    expect(baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

When I run on Node v14.0.0 it works and takes under 5 seconds, but if I switch to a newer version it takes over 20 seconds only to result in a `RangeError: Invalid string length` error pointing at `expect(baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();`. I'm using Jest 29.2.4 and React 18.2.0. What's going wrong here?